# Get SNMP enabled devices to test my app in public network

Tags: networking, network-protocols, snmp

I want to know if there is any `public IP` which is `snmp enabled` and I can test my application that I have developed across the network.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Enable SNMP on your windows/linux machine and test it. Or you want more specific machine?

Comment: @nIKUNJ - Yes i did that. But now I want any public ip, as I want to test it remotely.

Comment: http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/discussions/267539

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `public ip` which are `snmp enabled` by various network tools.

[PacketTrap pt360 ToolSuite](http://www.packettrap.com/product/pt360/links/snmp_primer.html) is one of those